# Why does "virsh list --all" shows running as normal user but "shut off" with sudo?

Tags: centos, kvm, virsh

The server1's **correct state is shut off** but when i run the command as normal user it shows the state as **running for normal user** and **shut off with sudo**

```
[msingh@localhost VMFiles]$ virsh list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 1     server1                        running

[msingh@localhost VMFiles]$ sudo virsh list --all
[sudo] password for msingh: 
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 -     generic                        shut off
 -     server1                        shut off
 -     server2                        shut off
 -     windows                        shut off

[msingh@localhost VMFiles]$
```

here is another command:

```
[msingh@localhost server1]$ sudo virsh dominfo server1
Id:             -
Name:           server1
UUID:           acd31081-b513-4e46-b2a2-20ad6bb9ac2e
OS Type:        hvm
State:          shut off
CPU(s):         1
Max memory:     1048576 KiB
Used memory:    1048576 KiB
Persistent:     yes
Autostart:      disable
Managed save:   no
Security model: selinux
Security DOI:   0

[msingh@localhost server1]$ virsh dominfo server1
Id:             1
Name:           server1
UUID:           8f6fa56a-b062-424a-9100-7f411df1c28b
OS Type:        hvm
State:          running
CPU(s):         1
CPU time:       18.8s
Max memory:     1024 KiB
Used memory:    2048 KiB
Persistent:     yes
Autostart:      disable
Managed save:   no
Security model: selinux
Security DOI:   0
Security label: unconfined_u:unconfined_r:svirt_t:s0:c290,c658 (enforcing)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `sudo virsh` will access the system libvirt instance.

`virsh` as an unprivileged user, will try to access the libvirt instance for that user.

You have a VM called `server1` in the user instance, and a VM called `server1` in the system instance, but these are not the same VM :).  Your output shows they have different memory configurations, for example.